# GDB break line in Bomb Project

Tags: gdb, breakpoints, compiler-flags

I have a CS project that I need to diffuse a bomb (the Mr.Evil bomb if you have ever heard about it), but I am having problems with gdb when I want to set break points to lines. After I open the file in gdb and try to break a t a random line I get this problem:

```
 gdb bomb 
 (gdb) break 15
 No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

In addition, even when i use the "file" command I get

```
 "/auto/bunter_usr/bomb": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

I realized that the problem is because my professor has not used the -g flag when he has compiled the file. In the situation I am, is there a way to set breakpoints to lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "/auto/bunter_usr/bomb": not in executable format: File format not recognized
>   I realized that the problem is because my professor has not used the -g flag

Your realization is incorrect. An executable compiled without `-g` would *not* produce above message.

Most likely, the file you are pointing GDB at is a shell script, which invokes the real executable (perhaps after setting some environment variables, or adding some command line flags). You want to debug the *real* executable, not the shell script.

Comment: I had to ssh to another account to run it

Answer (score 1):

u need to desassemble the binary and check for memory location and set breakpoints for those locations.

here's how you gonna do it  :   gdb> b *0x80456789

here's a cheat sheet for reference
http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/docs/gdbnotes-ia32.pdf